# How to get your name from GitHub using GraphQL and React Native?

Tags: javascript, function, react-native, rendering

I'm trying to get my GitHub username using GraphQL and React Native. I keep getting the error "Objects are not valid as a React child." I have tried declaring an array and appending the results to that array but then I just get an empty array. Therefore, I'm not 100% sure if I'm fetching the data correctly. I have also tried putting curly braces around mainFunction() as well as every suggested solution I could find on the internet but nothing seems to work. How can I get it working?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { Navigation } from 'react-native-navigation';
import { ApolloClient } from 'apollo-boost';

var asynchronousFunction = async () => {
  var response = await fetch('https://api.github.com/graphql', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'bearer ' + {TOKEN},
    },
    body: '{ "query": "{ viewer { name } } "}',
  });
  return response;
};

var mainFunction = async () => {
  var result = await asynchronousFunction();
  return result;
};

(async () => {
  console.log(await mainFunction());
})();

class Example extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>{JSON.stringify(mainFunction())}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default Example;
```

Comment: try this:
`'Authorization': "bearer " + {TOKEN}` and `body: "{ \"query\": \"{ viewer { name } } \"}"`

Comment: Hey I have updated the code with what you suggested but my result still just returns an empty array. Is there anything else you see wrong?

Comment: What does `console.log(response)` before the `return response` give you?

Did you follow the flow with first hitting `https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize` and then got token from here `https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token`? Also, keep the you need to escape the quotes as in : `body: "{ \"query\": \"{ viewer { name } } \"}"`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here

```
 render() {
    return (
      mainFunction()
    );
  }
```

The return statement from mainFunction is not a react component so it would always be an object so you should display is inside a Text using JSON stringify
Something like below

```
 render() {
    return (
      <View><Text>{JSON.stringify(mainFunction())}</Text></View>
    );
  }
```

Still its better to have a state and update it once you get the response which is the best practice when it comes to react

Comment: Hey thank you for pointing that out! I have updated the code with the things suggested and I'm no longer getting the "Objects are not valid as a React child." However, I'm still getting no actual results like my result is just an empty array.

Comment: Better check the graphql query, try login instead of name

Comment: I checked with the explorer and this was the body of the request better try that
{"query":"query { viewer { name } }","variables":{}}